# How to avoid failure on missing stash during unstash in Jenkinsfile in the first run?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Assume I want to wrap a command in a Jenkins stage between an unstash and stash command, e.g. for an static code analysis cache:

```
stage('Static code analysis') {
    steps {
    withMaven(jdk: "$JDK_INSTALLATION", maven: "$MAVEN_INSTALLATION", mavenOpts: "$MAVEN_OPTS", mavenSettingsConfig: "$MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE_ID") {
        unstash 'pmd-analysis-cache'
        sh "mvn verify -Pdevelopment -DskipTests"
        stash includes: 'pmd-analysis-cache', name: 'pmd-analysis-cache'
    }
}
```

This works the second, third, etc. time because the stash will be present once it has been created, but fail the first time because the stash `pmd-analysis-cache` isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Put a try / catch block around it

```
stage('Static code analysis') {
    steps {
    withMaven(jdk: "$JDK_INSTALLATION", maven: "$MAVEN_INSTALLATION", mavenOpts: "$MAVEN_OPTS", mavenSettingsConfig: "$MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE_ID") {
        try {
           unstash 'pmd-analysis-cache'
        } catch (e) {
           print "Unstash failed, ignoring"
        }
        sh "mvn verify -Pdevelopment -DskipTests"
        stash includes: 'pmd-analysis-cache', name: 'pmd-analysis-cache'
    }
}
```